# Repeat a Calculation for n times

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a Formula that returns a value x and I want to multiply this with another certain value y and I want to repeat this n Times and RETURN the SUM of all those multiplications. 
I have looked into OFFSET but couldnt quite figure it out and maybe thats not even the solution for this.

[image]

Comment: This is too vague to answer. Please provide more details, e.g. enough for someone to understand the basic layout of cells relevant to the computation.

Comment: Hello John, would It be possible to send you a screenshot? Cant post it here yet sadly since I am missing 10 reputation. The screenshot should explain my problem better.

Comment: @JLN post the screen shot on Imgur and [edit] the post to add the link to the photo

Comment: https://imgur.com/9v0uzYP I hope this makes more sense now. Let me know if something is still unclear! Thanks alot guys

Comment: Summarized: The value in front of the _@_ in Row Y gets multiplied with the value above in the Row X, this will be repeated for n-Times (e.g. on the screenshot n = 5) and in the end the product from each column gets summed up.

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX to set the end of the range and SUMPRODUCT with LEFT to get the correct number:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEFT(D2:INDEX(D2:I2,B1),FIND("@",D2:INDEX(D2:I2,B1))-1)*D1:INDEX(D1:I1,B1))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `SUMPRODUCT()` and `INDIRECT()`.

Assuming you can get the data left of the `@`, and transpose the data, use:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("$A$1:$A$"&ROW(A1)+$A$8-1),INDIRECT("$B$1:$B$"&ROW(B1)+$A$8-1))
```

[image]

Comment: My data is splitted into 2 rows tho instead of 2 columns. How would I do it then?

Comment: @JLN - Copy your data, paste special -> Transpose. Then remove the data `@...` from that column in any way you like.

Comment: The data needs to stay in 2 Rows and multiple columns tho